# Updating CSV from AD properties without @{} in results

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a script I am using to update a CSV file from my AD but it is currently outputting the results with @{} in the output CSV. So when I want to output the city it outputs @{city=toronto} instead of just toronto:

```
$USERS = Import-Csv "C:CSV import.csv"

$newCSV =ForEach ($User in $USERS) {
$Name = $User.name
[pscustomobject]@{
id = $user.id
name = $user.nameaddress1 = (Get-ADuser -Filter "name -like '$Name'" -properties StreetAddress | Select-Object StreetAddress)
address2 = (Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$Name'" -properties Office | Select-Object Office)
city = (Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$User.Name'" -properties City | Select-Object city)
}
}

$newCSV |export-csv "C:\CSVExport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: that means you stuffed a property ... not a VALUE ... into the new property. expand the prop OR just assign the value to the new prop. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you, I am newer to powershell, you are amazing!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating it, you can query the AD User once and then construct your export object with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Import-Csv "C:CSV import.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $Id = $_.Id
    try {
        Get-ADuser $_.Name -Properties StreetAddress, Office, City |
            Select-Object @{N='Id'; E={ $Id }}, Name, StreetAddress, Office, City
    }
    catch { Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message }
} | Export-csv "C:\CSVExport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```